# Error when I tried to read and write from Realm objects

Tags: ios, realm

I'm trying Realm for the first time but I'm getting errors when I tried to read and write from Realm, here is the code with the error lines commented:

```
class Test{

    dynamic var name = ""
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    @IBAction func show(sender: UIButton){

        let test = Realm().objects(Test) //cannot invoke 'objects' with no arguments
        label.text = test.name

    }


    @IBAction func set(sender: UIButton){
        let test = Test()
        let realm = Realm()
        test.name = "not using CoreData"
        realm.write{realm.add(test)} //cannot invoke write with argument list of type (()->_)
    }


}
```

here is the documentation page if anyone is interested: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try changing you declaration of the `Test` class to the following?

```
class Test : Object
```